# breadcrumbs_on_rails with twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I am using breadcrumbs_on_rails 2.2.0 with bootstrap 2.  Im confused.  It is not really creating breadcrumbs.  It is only creating the first level link.  In other words, as I navigate it isn't adding new breadcrumbs to the stack.

I am setting a default breadcrumb in the application controller

```
  before_filter :set_initial_breadcrumbs
  def set_initial_breadcrumbs
       add_breadcrumb 'cPanel', :controlpanel_path
  end
```

In controllers I am creating breadcrumbs in each action...something like:

```
  def show
      @model = Model.find(params[:id])
      add_breadcrumb "View Model", model_path(@model)
  end

 def edit
      @model = Model.find(params[:id])
      add_breadcrumb "Edit Model", edit_model_path(@model)
 end
```

If I navigate to the show page, then click on the edit link from there...the breadcrumb only shows the default crumb (back to the cPanel) and the "Edit Model" crumb (my current page).  But, the "Show Model" crumb (where my breadcrumb path originated) is not there.

This gem seems very easy to set up and configure.  But, I am evidently missing something.  I did notice an issue about 5 months ago alleging that breadcrumbs_on_rails has some conflicting method names with bootstrap (add_breadcrumb and render_breadcrumb).  I did some digging, and could only determine that bootstrap supplies styles for breadcrumbs but no methods for generating them.

Thanks for help

Comment: You are using `render_breadcrumbs` to ... render the breadcrumbs? Have you tried to `bundle update`? I am using this almost exactly the way you've described (only using InheritedResources) and it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: I am using render_breadcrumbs with an up to date gemfile. I have thrown this to the back burner, but hope to figure out how to maximize breadcrumbs soon.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same problem here. Seems the add_breadcrumb doesn't append to the existing crumbs.

Comment: yup...I still havent implemented breadcrumbs.  I switched to a gem called crummy.  But, am still not impressed.

Answer (score 2):

This gist might help you (created by Riyad Preukschas)

https://gist.github.com/riyad/1933884

Comment: if anyone needs Bootstrap 3 version(which uses Css separators) https://gist.github.com/equivalent/9972557